# Can R work with AWS S3 within a AWS Lambda function?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, rpy2

I'm looking for an approach to run a simulation algorithm developed in R in AWS. The input for the R model will come from S3 and the output will need to be written back to S3. The data scientist group at my organization are R experts and  my organization has identified as AWS as the enterprise cloud platform. Given this, I need to find a way to run the R simulation model in AWS.

I saw this blog (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/analyzing-genomics-data-at-scale-using-r-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/) which talks about using Lambda to run R code within Ptyhon using rpy2 package. I plan to follow the same approach. I was planning to implement the Lambda function as below-

1) Read input files from S3 to write to local lambda storage (/tmp). This will done using Python boto3 SDK.

2) Invoke R algorithm using rpy2. I plan to save the R algorithm as a .RDS file in S3 and load it using rpy2 and then run the R algorithm. R algorithm would write the output back to local lambda storage.

3) Write output from lambda storage to S3. Again this will be done using Python boto3 SDK.

As you can see, Python is used to interact with S3 and bring files to local lambda storage. R will read from local lambda storage and run the simulation algorithm. All R code will be wrapped within rpy2 in the lambda function. I was planning out this way because I was not sure if R can work with S3 directly.

I now realize that Lambda local storage is limited to 500 MB and I doubt if the input & output files will remain within this limit. I'm now trying to see if R can work directly with S3 within Lambda. If this is possible, I don't have to bring the files to local lambda storage and hence will not run out of space. Again, the R - S3 interaction will need to be wrapped inside rpy2. Is there a way to achieve this? Can the R Cloudyr library work in this scenario? Although I see examples of Cloudyr interacting with S3, but I don't see any example of this usage within Lambda using rpy2.

Any thoughts please?

Comment: May be the question is not so much about whether R can be used in a lambda function (as you note it, the answer is that it can) but about using storage within a lambda function when the size exceeds 500MB ?

Comment: @Igautier- Thanks for your response. You are right- I have a way to run R within Lambda, but this approach is limiting because of the Lambda size (500 MB) limitation. I think this is a hard limit and cannot be increased. I'm wondering if there is a different approach to run R in AWS.